# Connecting switches between two buildings, each building has it own mains electrical supply

Tags: networking, power-supply

I have two buildings (A + B) each with their own mains electrical supply. The buildings are about 20m from one another. Between the two buildings are the Cat6 cables (one active and two spares).

The Cat6 cable is terminated in a patching / data rack in each building.

Both buildings have their own patch panel and network switch. Building A houses the modem and router.

My concern is that I've heard having connected electrical devices / equipment, across two or more mains electrical supplies can cause issues / damage to the electrical devices / equipment due to different mains electrical supplies having different grounds / earths.

Is this a valid concern? And what can I do to rectify the issue?

Comment: If the supplies are properly earthed there should be no issue. In any case, Ethernet cables do not normally carry power, unless you are running PoE, which I don't think you will be.

Answer (score 18):

It won't be a problem. The Ethernet standards for twisted-pair have always required isolation of the signal wires from all local power supplies and grounds. In most equipment using twisted-pair Ethernet this is achieved simply by having all of the pairs run through transformers at each end. There is therefore no metallic connection between the switches or whatever the TP cable is plugged into, and therefore complete isolation, between the equipments' grounds and power supplies.

If you were using shielded twisted pair, you would want to connect its shield to building frame ground at one *and only one* end. This was a concern back in the days of 10Base2 and 10Base5 (Ethernet over coax).

Comment: I did not know this. So how does the signal maintain integrity if the switches on each end don't agree on what 0 volts is?

Comment: In each switch, the local logic level is referenced to the local "0". The local logic level is not transmitted to the other end, so it doesn't matter if the two ends have different reference levels for zero. What goes over the cable is a balanced AC-coupled signal, not referenced to either end's local ground. All that matters there is the polarity transitions, not the absolute levels. By the way, the logic signal in each switch isn't necessarily referenced to building frame ground either.

Comment: So what about PoE?

Comment: Ethernet uses [differential signalling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signaling). Thus the interface looks at difference between two wires, not absolute voltage levels. No common zero needs to be identified, as the difference will be equal no matter what gnd is with reference to the other end.

Comment: PoE is always transformer-isolated from the local AC supply.

Comment: @vidarlo: What about 10/100 Mbps Ethernet? Afaik, it does not use differential signalling (only 1Gbit and later does), although still magnetically isolated at the ends.

Comment: @grawity Ethernet over TP has always used differential signaling. You get it  basically free with transformers at each end.

Comment: @grawity it does. That's basically the reason behind twisted pair; noise will impact each wire almost equally, and thus the difference will be preserved.

Comment: @grawity - magnetically isolated = differential signaling. Just different names for communicating by changing electrical polarity via a transformer

Comment: @grawity Though not all differential signalling use transformers (you can also just use 2 pins out of your CPU/controller) - all transformer based signalling are essentially differential

Comment: @slebetman: Hmm, the definition of "differential signalling" that I had only meant that the two wires would transmit opposite signals (rather than signal+zero), and I've never heard about it requiring magnetic isolation. I was fairly sure that other implementations besides Ethernet don't use transformers at all...

Comment: @grawity He _just_ said that "not all differential signaling uses transformers". fyi it is not really necessary to transmit opposite signals. It's enough that the source connects the "low" or "return" side to signal ground through a resistor that matches the signal side's output impedance. Noise will then induce about the same voltage level in both the "hot" and "return" leads. So common mode noise rejection in the differential receiver works, even though the "return" lead is not actively driven. Many less-expensive pro audio items work this way (Behringer and Mackie, for ex.).

Comment: @grawity: That's exactly what I said. Not all differential signalling use transformers but all transformer based signalling are differential (due to how transformers work)

Answer (score 2):

If you're at all concerned about it, you can fairly cheaply use a fiber-optic connection instead. That completely avoids the issue by being non-conductive.

Gigabit media converters run for $50–100 a piece, allowing you to fairly cheaply user fiber instead. (Search Amazon or wherever for something like "fiber media converter" and you'll find plenty). This does require running fiber — and that's only easy if you can pull a pre-terminated fiber through existing conduit; that'll add around another $20 for the fiber. If anything is going to fail, it's going to be a media converter (or its power supply); therefor, keep a spare on hand. Total of under $200 including spares easily doable.

Note that there are multiple fiber connectors, so you need to make sure the pre-terminated fiber you buy matches the media converters. At the distance you're running (meters, not kilometers), everything will be multimode fiber and fairly low-power.

[Of course, if you have the tools and know-how to terminate fiber, that makes it easier, you can pull unterminated fiber through a much smaller or more tightly packed conduit. But then I suspect you'd have already considered this option.]